# NoMethodError when calling meta_data from Middleman Resource object

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I'm new to middleman and all the possibilities that i have. I want to make a deadly simple haml script that works as the index page which lists all my page types for faster navigation inside the project.

Here is the code:

```
---
layout: no_layout
---
- resources = sitemap.resources.sort {|a,b| a.url <=> b.url}

- pages = Array.new

- resources.each do |resource|
    - metadata = resource.metadata[:page]
    - if resource.mime_type.match(/^text\/html/) && metadata["title"]
        - element = Hash.new
        - element["url"] = resource.url     
        - element["title"] = metadata["title"]
        - element["desc"] = metadata["desc"]

        - if element["url"].start_with?('/')
            - element["url"].slice!(0) 
        - pages.push(element)

%h1 Page elements
- if pages.length > 0
    %ul
        - pages.each do |page|
            %li
                %a{:href => page["url"]} #{page["title"]}
                - if page["desc"]
                    %br
                    = page["desc"]
- else
    No pages found.
```

Sadly, Middleman generates the following error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `mime_type' for #<Middleman::Sitemap::Resource:0x000000069df020>
```

But the Middleman Documentation says, that the Resources object contains the method and i have some example code that also works that way.

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [`Resource#content_type`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/middleman-core/Middleman/Sitemap/Resource) instead.

```
$ bundle exec middleman console
> sitemap.resources[2].content_type
=> "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: That get me a "NoMethodError at / undefined method `content_type' for #<Middleman::Sitemap::Resource:0x000000053fd928>" error as well. I think something with my windows installation is wrong. Although i have a working sample on my machine which uses mime_type

Comment: You are right. My version was 3.0.13. After updating to 3.1.6, content_type works for me now. mime_type still not. Thanks!